# How to clear interval and set it again?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what i am trying to accomplish: when the last slide is reached fadeOut last slide and then fadeIn first slide, and then clearInterval ***(everything works with this part)***. Now my problem is that i want to setInterval **again** if it doesn't exists but I don't know how to make it happen:( 
I have tried to solve this with if statment but then my script doesn't work at all! 
So how can I RESTART my interval again? THANK YOU!! 
**Without** if statement like this it's working fine:

```
if(!intervalID){
    intervalID = setInterval(animate,5000);
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*check if intervalID don't exists messes UP!!*/
  if (!intervalID) {
    intervalID = setInterval(animate, 5000);
  }

  //Hide everything except first slide and controls

  $('.slidewrap div:not(.slidewrap div:first,.slidewrap .slide_controls)').hide();

  var animate = function() {

    /*if .pagination_active is last removeClass and addClass to .pagination_active 
             first li tag*/

    if ($('.pagination_active').is($('.slide_controls ul li:last'))) {
      $('.pagination_active').removeClass('pagination_active');
      $('.slide_controls ul li:first').addClass('pagination_active');
    } else {
      $('.pagination_active').removeClass('pagination_active').next().addClass('pagination_active');
    }

    /*if div.active is last fadeOut and add .active class 
             to the first div and fadeIn FIRST div then CLEAR INTERVAL and set intervalID to zero */

    if ($('.active').is($('.slidewrap div:last'))) {
      $('.active').fadeOut(1000).removeClass('active');
      $('.slidewrap div:first').addClass('active').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        intervalID = 0;

      });
    }

    //OR .active fadeOut and next div fadeIn
    else {
      $('.active').fadeOut(1000).next().fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $('.slidewrap div.active').removeClass('active').next('div').addClass('active');

      });
    }

  }

  var intervalID;
  intervalID = setInterval(animate, 3000);

});
```

Comment: You can't restart it; it's cleared, deleted. What you can do is start a NEW interval with the same function. –

Comment: @Blazemonger sir, you were editing my post and same time me also. So I lost your precious edit. If you feel necessary you can edit my answer, it will be pleasure for me

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After clear an interval you need to start it again with `setInterval()`.

It would be better to make function for your `setInterval()`

```
var intervalID = null;

function intervalManager(flag, animate, time) {
   if(flag)
     intervalID =  setInterval(animate, time);
   else
     clearInterval(intervalID);
}
```

Here `flag` is a `boolean` variable with value `true/ false`. `true` will execute `setInterval()` and `false` will `clearInterval()`;

Now you can use above function as you need.

For example:

```
intervalManager(true, animate, 300);  // for setInterval

intervalManager(false);  // for clearInterval
```

Comment: You cannot restart an Interval that already has been cleared. But why don't you simply start a new one?

Comment: THX thecodeparadox for your time and your answer! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 7):

**Just Example**

```js
var myVar 
function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
function myStartFunction() {
    myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
}
myStartFunction();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop time</button>
<button onclick="myStartFunction()">Start time</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is utility object that takes a callback and interval which you can use to start and stop an interval.

```
   //simple utility object to start and stop an interval       
    var IntervalUtil = function(functionCall, interval){


        var intervalObj = 0,
            INTERVAL    = interval;

        var callback = functionCall;

        function startTimer(){
            console.log('start timer', intervalObj)
            if(intervalObj === 0){
                intervalObj = setInterval(callback, INTERVAL)
            }
        }   

        function stopTimer(){
            clearInterval(intervalObj);
            intervalObj = 0;
            console.log('timer stopped', intervalObj);
        }

        return {
            startTimer : startTimer,
            stopTimer  : stopTimer
        }

    };
```

**You would use it like so **

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <meta name="author" content=""/>

    <title>Timer : setInterval()</title> 


    <style type="text/css">


    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        color:#000;
        line-height:1.3em;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:12px;
        outline:none;
    }

    a{
        outline:none;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#145486;
    }
    a span{
        color:#145486;
    }

    h1{
        font-weight:normal;
        font-size:32px;
    }

    body{
        background:#efefef;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .content{
        width:400px;
        padding:20px;
        margin:10px auto;
        background:#fff;
        border:solid 1px #ebebeb;
        text-align:left;
    }

    #toggleTimer{
        color:#fff;
        font-size:10px;
        padding:2px 7px;
        display:inline-block;
        background:#357cb7;
        border:solid 1px #0c8af4;
    }

    #toggleTimer.running{
        background:#f14621;
        border:solid 1px #ff4c00;
    }

    #output{
        padding:7px;
        font-size:10px;
        border:dashed 1px #ebebeb;
        background:#f8f8f8;
        margin-left:10px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    em{
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    </style>

</head>
<body>


<div class="content">

    <h1>Set Interval Code</h1>

    <a href="javascript:" id="toggleTimer" class="">Start Timer</a>

    <span id="output"></span>

    <br class="clear"/>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var demo = new Demo();
    });


    var Demo = function(){

        var self = this;

        var START_TEXT = "Start Timer",
            STOP_TEXT  = "Stop Timer";

        var $toggle = $('#toggleTimer'),
            $output = $('#output');

        var count = 0;

        var intervalUtil;

        function init(){
            intervalUtil = new IntervalUtil(printMessage, 1000);
            setClickHandler();
            return self;
        }   

        function setClickHandler(){
            $toggle.click(toggleTimer)
        }

        function toggleTimer(){

            $toggle.toggleClass('running');

            if($toggle.hasClass('running')){
                $toggle.text(STOP_TEXT);
                intervalUtil.startTimer();
            }else{
                $toggle.text(START_TEXT);
                intervalUtil.stopTimer();
            }
        }

        function printMessage(){        
            $output.html("printMessage called <em>" + (count++) + "</em> times");
        }

        return init();

    }


    //simple utility object to start and stop an interval       
    var IntervalUtil = function(functionCall, interval){


        var intervalObj = 0,
            INTERVAL    = interval;

        var callback = functionCall;

        function startTimer(){
            console.log('start timer', intervalObj)
            if(intervalObj === 0){
                intervalObj = setInterval(callback, INTERVAL)
            }
        }   

        function stopTimer(){
            clearInterval(intervalObj);
            intervalObj = 0;
            console.log('timer stopped', intervalObj);
        }

        return {
            startTimer : startTimer,
            stopTimer  : stopTimer
        }

    };  

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for timer which counts 15 sec then goes to main page, if there is click on screen resets timer to the start. It may be useful to someone. (x is counter for touch events) :

```
  var productInterval = null;
  var counterForGoToMainPage = 15;

  function startTimer(){
    counterForGoToMainPage--;

    if(counterForGoToMainPage == 0){
      clearInterval(productInterval);
      counterForGoToMainPage = 15;
      window.location.href = "/";
      }
  }

  function countTouches(event) {
  var x = event.touches.length;

    if(x == 1) { 
      clearInterval(productInterval);
      counterForGoToMainPage = 15;
      productInterval = setInterval(function(){
         startTimer();
      },1000);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project (using `Sveltekit`), I learned that you can loop between `setInterval` and `clearInterval` using `let` inside a function to define a NodeJS timer:

```
$: number = 0 //The "$" sign, in this case, is used to a make reactive statement 

const changeValue = (e: any) => {
    let changingValue = setInterval(() => {
        number += 0.01
        if (number >= 0.2) {
            clearInterval(changingValue)
        }
    }, 4)
}, 
changeValueAgain = (e: any) => {
    let changingValue = setInterval(() => {
        number -= 0.01
        if (number <= 0) {
            clearInterval(changingValue)
        }
    }, 4)
}
```

(I was using Typescript by the way)
It's simple, every time you call the functions, it creates a new NodeJS timer that get cleared when some condition is true

The `e` parameter was used to event handlers...